# CSS3: positioning rectangle at the same hight as text (`h1` and `p`) in header

Tags: html, css

Need a rectangle to the left of the `h1` and `p` elements in `header`. So I've used a div to group those 2 elements. Now need a rectangle to the left of them, that has a similar hight. See expected result for a better understanding.

1.-I've created a rectangle within a div.
2.-I've position it in the left side (next to the `<h1>` header).

3.-I want to put the rectangle at the same hight as the title (`<h1>`).

3.1.- I've tried using `padding` but it modified the size of the rectangle.

3.2.- I've tried `position:relative` without success.

4.- Also tried this without success:

```
header div#titulo {
border-left: 6px solid #000;
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

**My result:**

[image]

**Desired result:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
       <header>
    <div id="rectangle">  
    </div>
    <div id="titulo"><h1>omronlesdaz.com</h1>
    <p>Digital analyst - R programmer</p>
    </div>

    </header>
```

**CSS**:

```
header {
    /*text-align: left;*/
    padding: 0px 0px 40px 80px;
    background: gray;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}



#rectangle {
    border: dashed;
    float: left;
    width:10px;
    height:100px;
    background:#37B7DE;
    /*position: relative; #No effect*/
    /*padding: 20px; #Distorts the rectangle*/
}


#titulo {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**:

1 .- The solution need to group the `h1` and `p` to treat them as a one entity. So the rectangle is in the left of both (as they were one element), and not just at the left of the `h1` tag.

2.- The rectangle must not start at the top of the page, but at the same hight as the `h1` tag and end at the same hight of the `p` tag. This is why i think it's better to group them within a div.

Comment: Why do you don't try to set a border-left to you're h1 balise

Comment: @Alexis tried but not what i expected.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making a extra div at the first place? You don't need to make a div to apply the border property you can apply it on the h1 tag itself. The h1 act as a div itself. 
You can apply the border-left property on h1 tag and give it a left padding so that text appears at desired place.

CSS:

```
#titulo h1{
border-left: 6px solid #000;
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

See if this works.

Edit:

Just use this CSS:

```
#titulo h1{
margin: 0;
}
```

Solution: http://codepen.io/vikrantnegi007/pen/jPdpPy

Comment: Because it is just not the H1, but the H1 and P elements that must be surrounded by the rectangle in the left.

Comment: i got it, you need to reset the margin of the h1 block 
#titulo h1{
margin: 0;
}
It should solve the problem.

Comment: @vikrantenig007 may you edit your answer with the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Omar only you can do that. Just checked the tick mark on the left of the my answer. Happy to help.

Comment: @vikraintnegi007 you have gave me the idea how to solve it. It was about the margin property.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `border-left` and using padding to create some space. I'm not sure what you mean about treating them as one entity? You can just use the class made in the example and apply where needed to anything.

### **Updated working example below**

CSS:

```
.border-left {
  border-left-width: 5px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.border-left.red {
  border-left-color: red;
}
.border-left.green {
  border-left-color: green;
}
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/YXBvOR)

Comment: i've tried you code. But it just covers the `h1` tag, and should treat the `h1` and `p` tags as one. See edited question for more info.

Comment: See updated example. You can just apply the class to the elements that need the border. You can even use some extra classes control colour to make it more modular.

Comment: You missed the point of the question. See the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I've take u're HTML code and try to obtain you're result with border left :

```
header h1{
vertical-align:middle;
border-left:solid 5px red;
padding:15px;      
}
```

**Edit on JSFiddle** Better now

https://jsfiddle.net/uutohxxt/2/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `@vikrantnegi007` for the idea to solve the problem using `margin:`.

This is the solution:

Positioning the rectangle  under `<div id=rectangle>`:

```
#rectangle {
    float: left;
    margin: 80px 0px 10px 60px;
    width:10px;
    height:90px;
    background:#37B7DE; 
}
```

Positioning the `<h1>` and `<p>` tags under `<div id=titulo>`:

```
#titulo {
    float: left;
    margin: 60px 20px 10px 10px;

}
```

Result:

[image]